# Unable to access wordpress site on local host - err: This localhost page can’t be found

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, installation

Hi All i am facing issue with wordpress installation.

I downloaded wordpress setup from wordpress.org and moved it in var/www/html
but when i try to access it from localhost/wordpress. Iget the following error
**This localhost page can’t be found** .

but when i try localhost/wordpress/wp-admin it redirects to my other project wp-admin
like
http://localhost/xyz/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwordpress%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

I have not started with installation as yet. and i am able to access my other localhost wordpress sites. But any fresh downloaded wordpress site i am unable to access.

I am working in ubuntu

Things that i have tried 
renaming my .htaccess to .htaccess_temp - to ensure if it is ht access issue and i still get the same error.

Comment: What is your web server?

Comment: Have you check your folder permission 755 and file permission should be 644.

Comment: @EmptyBrain Apache2

Comment: @dineshkashera - Yes permissions are intact and owner is www-data:www-data

Comment: @rajiv Are you using your previous project database? if so then you need to change `siteurl` and `home` from the database `wp_option` table.

Answer (score 2):

Got it fixed. There was a hidden wp-config in my root folder which was interrupting the flow.. once deleted the link works fine